# Is there a list of intermediary banks for the U.S. wire transfer system?

Tags: united-states, banking, international-transfer, wire-transfer

I've been hearing that there are only 4 banks that actually service international U.S. wire transfers. Those banks then forward transfers to all domestic banks.

Which institutions are those? Secondly, why only those institutions?

Answer (score 2):

> I've been hearing that there are only 4 banks that actually service international U.S. wire transfers.

This is not true. Depending on the currency pair, you will find quite a few banks.

In general Bank of America, Bank of New York, Citi, HSBC, Barclays, JPMC, Wells Fargo, etc all offer dollar clearing